# How to render the properties of the view model's base class first when using ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties for a generic edit view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

When I use the `ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties` in order to loop the properties (with an additional `Where(modelMetadata => modelMetadata.ShowForEdit && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(modelMetadata))`), and thereby create a generic edit view, the properties of the view model's base class are rendered last.

Is it possible to use a clever OrderBy() or is there another way to first get the properties of the base class, and then the sub class'?

`Reverse` won't do the trick since the ordering of each class' properties is perfectly fine.

A workaround would of course be composition + delegation, but since we don't have mixins, it's too un-DRY IMHO, why I seek a better solution if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with another solution that doesn't use inheritance.

The case is; based on a type, only a sub-set of the properties should be editable.

I solved it by defining a set of property lambda expressions for each type.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties I dont see any information that shows if a property is part of the Model class or of its Superclass.

One way would be to put an attribute on the properties of the Superclass. If this is a attribute "DisplayMeAtTheTop" it could be used by other properties too, that have to be on top.

Comment: Before asking my question, I found a blog post (http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/11/Ordering-fields-in-ASPNET-MVC-2-templated-helpers.aspx) where the author created an Order(int) attribute in order to control the ordering.

I also investigated the properties of ModelMetadata but couldn't find anything useful for an OrderBy, but was hoping I had overlooked something.

I was hoping to find a simpler solution to my problem than a custom attributes, but it's at least one way to solve the problem.

Comment: Interesting post. This ordering thing should be in the default MetaDataProvider. Its pretty much essential.